# when we mouse over a disabled button in FireFox,The title can't display

Tags: html, firefox

when we mouse over a disabled button in FireFox,The title can't display.In IE ,this action is OK.

`<input type='button' disabled='disabled' title='show title' value='Test'/>`

As above, In IE ,when we mouse over this button ,the "show title" will display. But in firefox it can't work. Somebody can help me?it will be very appreciate.

Comment: As of Firefox 8, the title of a disabled element is displayed upon hover.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a (very old, and very abandoned) bug. See Mozilla Bugs [#274626](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274626) [#436770](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436770)

I guess this could also be explained as intended behaviour.

One horrible Workaround that comes to mind is to overlap the button with an invisible div with a title attribute using z-index; another to somehow re-activate the button 'onmouseover' but to cleverly intercept and trash any click event on that button.

This is quoted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034820/firefox-does-not-show-tooltips-on-disabled-input-fields).