# Tooltip is not displayed for a disabled html button in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, firefox, button, tooltip, disabled-control

Mozilla Firefox will not display tooltips of disabled controls. Is there another way to display them?

I would prefer a solution without using javascript.

There is an easy method I could find is to change in css styles is

```
button,
input
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

button[disabled]:hover:before,
input[disabled]:hover:before
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    content: attr(title);
    background-color: #ffffe1;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 10pt;
    font-size: 8pt;         
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index:10000;
    padding:2px;
}
```

This works fine in case of button element, but does not work for the input type button control/element.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034820/firefox-does-not-show-tooltips-on-disabled-input-fields

Answer (score 2):

trying using a javascript tool tip to add dynamic html tool tips.  Then you wont' need to rely on how different browsers render tool tips for disabled html elements.

Comment: `code`
 //To display tooltip for disabled button in firefox browser.
 $(window).load(function() {
  if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   $("input").each(function() {
    if ((this.type == "button" || this.type == "submit") && this.disabled) {

     var wrapperSpan = $("<span>");
     wrapperSpan.css({ position: "relative" });
     $(this).wrap(wrapperSpan);

     var span = $("<span>");
     span.attr({
      "title": this.title,
      "class": "DisabledButtonToolTipSpan"
     });
     $(this).parent().append(span);
    }
   });
  }
 });

Comment: .DisabledButtonToolTipSpan
{
 position :absolute;
 z-index  :1010101010;
 display  :block;
 width  :100%;
 height  :100%;
 top   :0;   
}