# How to show or not show required field aestrisk when checkbox is selected in ASP.net page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

[image]

to do this I have to refresh the page? if so then I have to keep all the user entered details.
Any simple elegant solution please?

Comment: Why the heck has this been down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a span that contains the asterisk, you can simply use JQuery to clear the text when the checkbox is cleared.

```
$("#idOfCheckbox").click(function() {

   if(this.is(':checked') == true) {
     $("#idOfAsterisk").text("");
   }
});
```

Comment: how come the asterisk will be removed without refresh the page?

Comment: your code works perfect, but I still wonder how the page shows or not shows * without refreshing page? Ajax?

Comment: @kneethan Hi, sorry about the wait, might be on different timezones.  JQuery and javascript are dynamic languages, that `.click()` causes the function code to be executed whenever a user "clicks" that element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, if you got time could you pls check my other question where I didn't satisfy with given answers since those are not working 100%, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173655/dropdownlist-inside-div-to-show-onmouseover-tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to toggle a CSS class on that control. So you could use the following for example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="True"></asp:Label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /> <br />
```

and then some CSS:

```
/* Required Field Asterix Suffix */

.form-field-required:after {
    color: red;
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and then some JS to do the toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#Label1').addClass('form-field-required');
    else
       $('#Label1').removeClass('form-field-required');
    }
});
```

});

On PostBack because you are keeping the viewstate for Label1 you will still have the asterix or not as needed.