# onmouseover event not firing in Firefox on div tags with only input fields

Tags: html, firefox

I'm trying to display a button  when an input field is hovered over.   Everything works fine in chrome and IE but in Firefox it fails.  Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en-US">
<head/>
<body>
<div onmouseover="alert('Firefox/chrome/ie all trigger me')">foo</div>
<div onmouseover="alert('Chrome/ie trigger me but fire fox won't')">
<input id="date_01" type="text" disabled="" tabindex="1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mousing over the first div causes the alert to display.  Mousing over the second div doesn't cause the alert to trigger in Firefox.

Is there any reason this doesn't work properly in firefox? or any common work arounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox does not show tooltips on disabled input fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034820/firefox-does-not-show-tooltips-on-disabled-input-fields)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate: [bug 274626](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274626) has been resolved in Firefox 8, yet the issue mentioned here is still present. Probably related still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with the fact that the input field is disabled? [Firefox does not show tooltips on disabled input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034820/firefox-does-not-show-tooltips-on-disabled-input-fields)

The **disabled=""** attribute is misleading - as long as you have the word **disabled**, it really doesn't matter what you're setting it to, the field will still be disabled.

Comment: Firefox doesn't fire any events on disabled form controls, apparently for compatibility reasons, but as mentioned in the linked question, things are slowly starting to move, although not as quickly as I'd like...

Comment: tried removing any reference to "disabled" in that tag and still no dice.