# Tooltip Not Working On TextBox At A Time Of Enabled="false"

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

TextBox is `Enabled="false"`, which is why the tooltip is not showing on TextBox.

What should I do to show the ToolTip without changing state of TextBox?

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" data-original-title="Description" Enabled="false"  runat="server" Class="txtDescription form-control tooltips"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox does not show tooltips on disabled input fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034820/firefox-does-not-show-tooltips-on-disabled-input-fields). See second answer.

Comment: I can't see ToolTip in Chrome also. Because this is an Enable="False" TextBox.

Comment: The second answer is a fix pertaining to disabled inputs in Bootstrap in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ReadOnly="true" and it's work.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" data-original-title="Description" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Class="txtDescription form-control tooltips"></asp:TextBox>
```